# arangoimp of graph from CSV file

Tags: csv, graph, arangodb

I have a network scan in a TSV file that contains data in a form like the following sample

```
source IP      target IP       source port    target port
192.168.84.3   192.189.42.52   5868           1214
192.168.42.52  192.189.42.19   1214           5968
192.168.4.3    192.189.42.52   60680          22
....  
192.189.42.52  192.168.4.3     22             61969
```

Is there an easy way to import this using arangoimp into the (pre-created) edge collection networkdata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine [the TSV importer](https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpBulkImports/Arangoimp.html#importing_tsv_data), if it wouldn't fail converting the IPs (fixed in ArangoDB 3.0), so you need a bit more conversion logic to get valid CSV. One will use the [ede attribute conversion option](https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpBulkImports/Arangoimp.html#attribute-naming-and-special-attributes) to convert the first two columns to valid `_from` and `_to` attributes during the import.

You shouldn't specify column subjects with blanks in them, and it should really be tabs or a constant number of columns. We need to specify a `_from` and a `_to` field in the subject line.

In order to make it work, you would pipe the above through `sed` to get valid CSV and proper column names like this:

```
cat /tmp/test.tsv  | \
  sed -e "s;source IP;_from;g;" \
      -e "s;target IP;_to;" \
      -e "s; port;Port;g" \
      -e 's;  *;",";g' \
      -e 's;^;";' \
      -e 's;$;";' | \
   arangoimp --file - \
      --type csv \
      --from-collection-prefix sourceHosts \
      --to-collection-prefix targetHosts \
      --collection "ipEdges" \
      --create-collection true \
      --create-collection-type edge
```

Sed with these regular expressions will create an intermediate representation looking like that:

```
"_from","_to","sourcePort","targetPort"
"192.168.84.3","192.189.42.52","5868","1214"
```

The generated edges will look like that:

```
{ 
  "_key" : "21056", 
  "_id" : "ipEdges/21056", 
  "_from" : "sourceHosts/192.168.84.3", 
  "_to" : "targetHosts/192.189.42.52", 
  "_rev" : "21056", 
  "sourcePort" : "5868", 
  "targetPort" : "1214" 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there an Arangodb 3.0 release date? (I know it is currently in beta.)

Comment: We're aproaching later this week. RC3 is just being released.